# Log a call's execution time using wamp

Tags: apache, wamp

Is there a way to log how long a call takes, as currently it only logs the time the call was made? I need the actual duration.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain a little more about what you are trying to log. Do you mean how long a page takes to load and execute? Or how long it takes to call a specific PHP funtion within a page script?

Comment: how long a page takes to load after its been called yes

Answer (score 0):

Well one way to do it is using the already existing Apache logging feature.

So first check that you have this module activated in httpd.conf `LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so` it probably is.

Then change your `LogFormat` parameter to add these 2 new options

So if you start with

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

Then change it to

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" $$%T/%D$$" combined
```

Then make sure that the `CustomLog` parameter is using the newly changed `combined` output.

```
CustomLog "c:/wamp/logs/access.log" combined
```

All the directories in this example assume you are using WAMPServer, if not dont use the actual directories I have in this example.

> `%T` shows The time taken to serve the request, in seconds.
>
> `%D` shows The time taken to serve the request, in microseconds

This will give you the extra parameters at the end of each line in the `access.log` like so

> mypc - - [24/Feb/2015:11:10:58 +0000] "GET /index.php?img=favicon HTTP/1.1" 200 1429 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0" $$0/5000$$

You can change the `$$` symbols I used here to whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks man, this works great. I tweaked it somewhat, but great nonetheless.